# How do I Ignore empty properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, soapui

I have a class which name is CustomerPermission.
This is my class

```
public class CustomerPermission {
        public string ContactInfo { get; set; }
        public Boolean CallStatus { get; set; }
        public string CallModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public Boolean SalesStatus { get; set; }
        public string SalesModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I fill the following class from db.
This is my code which fill properties.

```
List<CustomerPermission> customerPermission=new List<CustomerPermission>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    CustomerPermission cusPer=new CustomerPermission();
    cusPer.ContactInfo=dr["contact_info"].ToString();
    cusPer.CallStatus=dr["call_status"].ToString();
    cusPer.CallModifiedDate=dr["call_date"].ToString();
    cusPer.SalesStatus=dr["sales_status"].ToString();
    cusPer.SalesModifiedDate=dr["sales_date"].ToString();
}
```

The following describes my output in soapui.

```
 <b:CustomerPermission>
  <b:CallModifiedDate>17.11.2021 11:30:00</b:CallModifiedDate>
  <b:CallStatus>false</b:CallStatus>
  <b:ContactInfo>xxxxx</b:ContactInfo>
  <b:SalesModifiedDate>17.11.2021 11:30:00</b:SalesModifiedDate>
  <b:SalesStatus>true</b:SalesStatus>
</b:CustomerPermission>

<b:CustomerPermission>
  <b:CallModifiedDate i:nil="true"/>
  <b:CallStatus i:nil="true"/>
  <b:ContactInfo>xxx@mails.com</b:ContactInfo>
  <b:SalesModifiedDate>17.11.2021 11:29:47</b:SalesModifiedDate>
  <b:SalesStatus>false</b:SalesStatus>
</b:CustomerPermission>
```

If the contact info is `mail` I dont want to see `CallStatus` and `CallModifiedDate`. Call information should be seen only if a phone number exist.

I would like to my output to be as follows:

```
<b:CustomerPermission>
  <b:CallModifiedDate>17.11.2021 11:30:00</b:CallModifiedDate>
  <b:CallStatus>false</b:CallStatus>
  <b:ContactInfo>xxxxx</b:ContactInfo>
  <b:SalesModifiedDate>17.11.2021 11:30:00</b:SalesModifiedDate>
  <b:SalesStatus>true</b:SalesStatus>
</b:CustomerPermission>  

<b:CustomerPermission>
  <b:ContactInfo>xxx@mails.com</b:ContactInfo>
  <b:SalesModifiedDate>17.11.2021 11:29:47</b:SalesModifiedDate>
  <b:SalesStatus>false</b:SalesStatus>
</b:CustomerPermission>
```

Comment: Are you asking because yuou want to reduce the size of the data transmission? (I'm also curious how you manage to get `dr["call_date"].ToString()` to load a null into your prop). Post the XSD so we can see

Comment: Yes I ask for this. I will add null control to this property.

Answer (score 1):

I get the feeling you might need to have, for example, some more intelligent control of serializing

```
public string CallModifiedDate { get; set; }
public bool ShouldSerializeCallModifiedDate => !ContactInfo.Contains("@");

public bool CallStatus { get; set; }
public bool ShouldSerializeCallStatus => !ContactInfo.Contains("@");
```

Comment: how can I use ShouldSerialize when I fill the properties from db

Comment: You don't use it; the XmlSerializer does